# Zero mass Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

When mass in Kerr metric is put to zero we have $$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+\frac{r^{2}+a^{2}\cos^{2}\theta}{r^{2}+a^{2}}dr^{2}+\left(r^{2}+a^{2}\cos^{2}\theta\right)d\theta^{2}+\left(r^{2}+a^{2}\right)\sin^{2}\theta d\phi^{2},$$
where $a$ is a constant. This is a flat metric. What exactly is the coordinate transformation that changes this into the usual Minkowski spacetime metric form $$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2}?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates

Comment: Have a look at this paper: “Cartesian Kerr-Schild variation on the Newman-Janis ansatz”, [1601.03532](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03532).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in @Umaxo's comment,
according to [Boyer-Lindquist coordinates - Line element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates#Line_element):

> The coordinate transformation from Boyer–Lindquist coordinates
> $r,\theta,\phi$ to Cartesian coordinates $x,y,z$ is given
> (for $m\to 0$} by:
> $$\begin{align}
>   x &= \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\cos\phi \\
>   y &= \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\sin\phi \\
>   z &= r\cos\theta
>   \end{align}$$

Proving that this is the desired transformation
is a straight-forward but very tedious task.
First calculate the differentials of the above:
$$\begin{align}
dx &= \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}\sin\theta\cos\phi\ dr \\
   &+ \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\cos\theta\cos\phi\ d\theta \\
   &- \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\sin\phi\ d\phi \\
dy &= \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}\sin\theta\sin\phi\ dr \\
   &+ \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\cos\theta\sin\phi\ d\theta \\
   &+ \sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\theta\cos\phi\ d\phi \\
dz &= \cos\theta\ dr 
   - r\sin\theta\ d\theta
\end{align}$$

Then insert these differentials into the Minkowski metric:
$$\begin{align}
ds^2 &= -dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 \\
     &\text{... omitting the lengthy algebra here,
    exploiting $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$ several times} \\
  &= -dt^2 
   +\frac{r^2+a^2\cos^2\theta}{r^2+a^2}dr^2
   +\left(r^2+a^2\cos^2\theta\right)d\theta^2
   +\left(r^2+a^2\right)\sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2
\end{align}$$
which is the Kerr-metric for zero mass $M$, angular momentum $J$,
and charge $Q$.

Answer (score 4):

The transformation is given in page 15 of this paper: [The Kerr spacetime: A brief introduction](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622)

BTW there is a 2017 paper that claims that the mass zero Kerr metric is not actually equivalent to Minkowski metric but is a wormhole instead: [Zero mass limit of Kerr spacetime is a wormhole](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07787)

Comment: In the first paper you cited, the x, y, and z coordinates are not the typical x, y, and z coordinates. This still describes some curved surface. I tend to believe the second paper gets it right